# Corona/Android check if user liked my facebook page

Tags: android, facebook, lua, facebook-like, coronasdk

I'm developing a game in Corona SDK.
I want to allow users like my facebook page via my app and then they can get a bonus in my game. Such solution is for example implemented in Tap Tycoon.
After click "like it" I'm doing something like that:
system.openURL("fb://page/pageID")
and then facebook opens my page on facebook. I can click 'like it' button, but now, how can I check if user really liked my page? I know I should know userID and pageID, but how can I get user id doing that this way?

If this is not possible, what can I do to get the desirable effect in different way? I want to avoid logging users to facebook via my app and getting permissions to read user's profile etc.

I'd be grateful for any advice.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Giving the user anything for liking your page is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: And bonus for like  is something done in most productions. There's no way you are going to know that. Even after you log user in it is something difficult to determine, because they might have liked your site earlier, might have removed it straight away etc etc.

Comment: @Krystian If that is done in most productions, so how can I do this? In Tap Tycoon I clicked like it button then I got redirectedto facebook app, I liked it, then I clicked return button and when I came back to the game, I got a bonus, so it has to be possible to do it.

Comment: it IS possible (as you can read in my answer), but it´s not allowed. so don´t do it. report apps if they do it.

Comment: @r3m4k3 what I meant is that plenty of productions give bonus for likes, I have never seen a game which actually checked this. I don't even have private facebook account and I always get the bonuses ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would only be possible by authorizing a user with the `user_likes` permission. But you will not get that permission approved in the review process, because what you want to achieve is not allowed. You can´t reward users in any way for liking your Page.

You MUST read the platform policy before creating any App: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Ok then, but how for example Tap Tycoon developers and others developers did it if Facebook doesn't approve this feature?

Comment: just because you see it somewhere does not mean you should. it´s not allowed, that is a fact. you should report it to facebook if you see someone rewarding users for liking a page, they may have get user_likes approved for something else and implemented the like gate later.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But what about this section: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/overview

Comment: i dont see any relation to the topic of this question, to be honest.

Comment: One paragraph about games from Facebook Policy: Use Facebook Payments Offers If You Reward People for Actions Involving Third Parties

Comment: how is that related to liking a page? not sure where you want to go with this, but everything you need to know is in my answer. there´s really nothing else to it, you are not allowed to reward users in any way for liking your facebook page.